# two figures side by side with each a caption using memoir

Tags: graphics, memoir

i tried to use the answer of a previous question and can put two figures side by side. when I try to put a caption on each of them, only the second figure appears.

Example code with the caption lines commented out (replace figure to run!)

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper
    ]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

text

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subbottom{
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{figures/c29}
        \end{minipage}
%       \caption{Necker Cube\index{Necker Cube}: A cube or a corner?}
        \label{fig:2.9}
    } 
    \subbottom{
        \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{figures/c210}
        \end{minipage}
        %           \caption{Two Faces or a Vase?}
        \label{fig:2.10}
    }
\end{figure}


more text 

\end{document}
```

how to arrange with two captions?

Comment: Why are you using `\subbottomk` in the first place? Just add `\caption` + `\label` into the min minipages. Good idea to also add `\centering` into the minipages and change `[width=0.95\textwidth]` to `[width=0.95\linewidth]`. TIP: if you give `graphicx` the package option `demo` it ignores all images and make blaqck square sample images instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondered if memoir was one of the class/packages which moved captions around (like floatrow).  As it turned out, not a problem.  Since I had already done the work...

The default for figure (IIRC) is [tbp], which is why the float was moved to the top of the page.

```
\documentclass[msmallroyalvopaper
    ]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

text

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Necker Cube\index{Necker Cube}: A cube or a corner?}
        \label{fig:2.9}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Two Faces or a Vase?}
        \label{fig:2.10}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


more text 

\end{document}
```